# JDK's ClassLoaderHelper has no usage

Tags: java, classloader, helper

[ClassLoaderHelper](https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/openjdk-8/jdk/src/solaris/classes/java/lang/ClassLoaderHelper.java.shtml) has no meaning

```
class ClassLoaderHelper {
    private ClassLoaderHelper() {}
    static File mapAlternativeName(File lib) {
        return null;
    }
```

I didn't find any usages for `mapAlternativeName` which can't be overridden (static)

Also comment has no real meaning

> ```
> /**
>  * Returns an alternate path name for the given file
>  * such that if the original pathname did not exist, then the
>  * file may be located at the alternate location.
>  * For most platforms, this behavior is not supported and returns null.
>  */
> ```

Is it just leftover from previous version or just a designating Helper class for future use?

**EDIT**

I found a relevant bug (Resolution: Unresolved) [JDK-7157665 : Use ClassLoaderHelper for all native library loads](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7157665)

> The fix for 7134701 needs to be updated to make the same change for the other code paths where
>   native libraries are loaded: namely
>   - where non-bootstrap classloaders are used and
>   - where System.load() is called
>
> In both those cases an absolute pathname is provided, but (on Mac) we should attempt to load the
>   original file first and on Mac, for compatibility with Apple's jdk 6, we should look for a .jnilib
>   variant if the original name was *.dylib, and it wasn't found.

Comment: interesting, even if there are callers of this class methods, they are known to return the same thing all the time, weird class indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download Java 12 source and found that class was changed, added constant:

```
/**
 * Indicates, whether PATH env variable is allowed to contain quoted entries.
 */
static final boolean allowsQuotedPathElements = true;
```

And it is used in `ClassLoader`:

```
if (ClassLoaderHelper.allowsQuotedPathElements && ...
```

So this class can't be deleted (and it's designating Helper class for ClassLoader)